# Right rotate an array by k elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, data-structures

The code I tried was showing IndexError: list assignment index out of range. Please help me to sort out this problem.
The code has been below :

```
def rightrotate(source,k):
    temp_array=[0]*k
    i=len(source)-1
    j=0
    while(i>=k+1):
        temp_array[j]=source[i]
        i-=1
        j+=1
    i=len(source)-1
    while(i>=k):
        source[i]=source[i-k]
        i-=1
    i=0
    j=0
    while(i<k):
        source[i]=temp_array[j]
        i+=1
        j+=1

source=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
rightrotate(source,2)
print(source)
```

Comment: what is the desired output for this example?

Comment: This does not look right a rotation since the order is not preserved (aka the first one should be [60,70,10,20,30,40,50] )

Comment: @Ma0 yes you are right it should be [60,70,10,20,30,40,50] when k=2 & [50,60,70,10,20,30,40] when k = 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
source=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]

def right_rot(lst, k):
    return lst[-k:] + lst[:-k]

print(right_rot(source, 2))  # -> [60, 70, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```